# Transferring csv file from FTP to Salesforce.?

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, ftp

Can someone help me in this and ways to do it and some sample code that is helpful for me.?
I have no idea how to start this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to load the data from the csv into sfdc, not just the file by itself?

You can use Jitterbit to do this, which is a free data loader tool and is able to work with FTP without any customization. For more info, check:
http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/

Comment: Is this free of cost..or only for 30 days..Also can you also suggest me some coding ways.??

Comment: Also can we schedule the transfer.??

Comment: There is a free version which is not a trail. The program also includes a scheduler indeed.

You could check out their youtube channel for some extra information: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7A314A442BFBF64C.

Or just go through the documentation provided on their website.

Answer (score 0):

The [Salesforce Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) is a free tool supplied by SFDC that can be used graphically and also from the command line. You can schedule loads by scripting the command line inteface. You'd need to get the file from FTP to local disk to use it, as Data Loader doesn't talk to FTP as far as I know.